# Is it normal for a bolt+nut that goes through a control arm bushing to still be able to spin after being torqued down?

Tags: suspension, torque-specification, bushing, control-arm

The car in question is a '97 Civic. The bolt of concern connects the damper fork to the lower control arm trough a bushing. It's encircled in red in the following picture.

[image]

I torqued the bolt down to 64 Nm by torqueing the bolt while holding the nut with a socket wrench. This was done with the suspension at ride height, the lower control arm jacked up so it's carrying the weight of the vehicle.

I noticed that I can still turn the bolt+nut (without holding the nut) with relatively little effort. Is this normal? I'm worried that if the pinching force is so small that I can still turn the bolt+nut that the bushing itself isn't pinched properly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having installed suspension on many an EJ Civic, I can tell you that it's normal for that bolt to spin independent of the control arm.  The reason it spins freely now is because in removing it, you cleaned out the decade and a half of dirt and rust that had accumulated in there.

As long as you used a new locking nut and torqued it to spec*, it will not come apart in normal use.  The forces acting on that bolt during driving are vertical and the bolt isn't supposed to "pinch" the bushing, rather just lock the control arm assembly together.

*Full disclosure: I probably only replaced the locking nut one out of every ten or so times.  Thousands of hours of commuting and thousands of track laps never resulted in a control arm bolt coming loose.